# Recover backup set up of two external hard drives

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

My backup set up consists on two external hard drives. They are named HDD1 and HDD2. This kind of set up what originally started by another question: [Second HDD backup for OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235570/second-hdd-backup-for-os-x)

External HDD1 is now broken, it's not working because I dropped it. So now what should I do to built external HHD1 from HDD2? I had a look into the data that is inside HDD2 and seems to be fine. Seems a simple copy paste to a new HDD1 would be enough at least to get started again. However, a better alternative would be to have everything as when HDD1 and HDD2 where both working.